# Parsing a Date string with AFNetworking (dateFormatter)

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm changing my app so it could parse my JSON through AFNetworking and I'm getting an error when I try to change my date string with dateFormatter. I have a NSObject called **"UpcomingRelease"**, a CollectionViewController called **"UpcomingReleasesViewController"** and a destinationViewController called **"ReleaseViewController"**

This my old code:

*** UpcomingRelease.h**

```
@interface UpcomingRelease : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *release_date;

- (NSString *) formattedDate;

@end
```

*** UpcomingRelease.m**

```
- (NSString *) formattedDate {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.release_date];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate];
}
```

*** ReleaseViewController.h** (destinationViewController)

```
#import "UpcomingRelease.h"

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *singleRelease;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *release_date;
```

*** ReleaseViewController.m**

```
@synthesize singleRelease = _singleRelease;
@synthesize release_date = _release_date;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if([_singleRelease objectForKey:@"release_date"] != NULL)
    {
        self.release_date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _singleRelease.formattedDate];
    }
    else
    {
        self.release_date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Releasing Soon"];
    }
}
```

I get an error saying "Property 'formattedDate' not found on object of type 'NSDictionary').

Comment: seems like the object with the property formattedDate has been released when you try to access it. I think the probelm is not in the date formatter but how you are dealing with the object that hs this property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error already says that `NSDictionary` doesn't have a property called `formattedDate`. And right now you are calling `_singleRelease.formattedDate` and `_singleRelease` is a `NSDictionary`.

Change your code to the following:

```
if([_singleRelease objectForKey:@"release_date"] != NULL)
{
    NSString *rd = [_singleRelease objectForKey:@"release_date"]; // I assume that this is a string
    UpcomingRelease *upcoming = [[UpcomingRelease alloc] init];
    upcoming.release_date = rd;

    self.release_date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", upcoming.formattedDate];
}
```

Comment: UpcomingRelease is a NSObject, singleRelease is a NSDictionary for my destinationViewController (ReleaseViewController)

Comment: For what reason are you using UpcomingRelease?

Comment: The tutorial I used as base had the code set up that way. But i'm guessing is to store the NSStrings and to change the date so it's readable.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer based on the additional details you provided. Does this work?